# не удается подключиться к postgresql со своего пк через beekeeper studio

Tags: postgresql

установил на удаленный сервер (debian) postgresql настроил создал нового пользователя и т.д настроил подключения (в postgresql.conf раскоментировал listen_address='0.0.0.0' в pg_hba.conf добавил host all all 0.0.0.0 scram-sha256) пытаюсь через beekeeper studio подключиться пишет "there was a problem connect ECONNREFUSED ip:5432"
на сервере еще установлен ufw ,но я открыл порт 5432
кто ставил на сервер постгрес ,помогите плиз

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `scram-sha256` попробуйте `md-5`